# custom keyboard UITextField inputView xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode5, uiinputviewcontroller

I am adding a custom keyboard to a view using inputView linked to a UITextField.  I have set the size at Width 216, Height 320.  I have it entering from the bottom on a portrait orientation.  I want it to only cover 216 pixels of the screen but now when it comes up with the keyboard hugging the left side and has the correct aspect ratio. However there is a gray background that extends from the right edge of the keyboard to the right side of the view.  Is there any way to remove this so it is clear and I can see the right side of the view?  I have tried setting the background of the view to clear color and tried everything I can think of.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't do it, because with keyboard opening the view moves up, so there are the "empty" rectangle in the 216x320 pts.